# Propiedad datesDisabled no bloquea fechas de Datepicker

Tags: datepicker, jquery-datepicker

Tengo un `Datepicker` que estoy utilizando dentro de un formulario hecho con `Bootstrap 4`, ahora necesito deshabilitar las fechas que son feriado dentro del año pero no logro hacerlo.

El código del llamado del Datepicker dentro del formulario:

```
<label class="col-form-label">Fecha Hasta:</label>
<div class="form-group form-bordered col-md-2 m-b-10">
    <input type="text" name="fechaHasta" class="form-control" id="fechaFin" placeholder="Select Date" value="<%=request.getAttribute("fechaHasta")%>" onclick="ShowCalendarFin()" />
</div>
```

El código del Datepicker:

```
function ShowCalendarFin(){

    $("#fechaFin").datepicker({
            changeMonth : true, 
            changeYear : true, 
            autoclose: true, 
            firstDay : 1, 
            minDate : new Date(2005, 0, 1),
            yearRange : '2005:'
                    + String((new Date()).getFullYear() + 1),
            dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy", 
            language: "es",
            dayNames : [ "Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles",
                    "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado" ],
            dayNamesMin : [ "Do", "Lu", "Ma", "Mi", "Ju", "Vi", "Sa" ],
            monthNames : [ "Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril",
                    "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre",
                    "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre" ],
            monthNamesShort : [ "Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May",
                    "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic" ],
            datesDisabled: [
                            "01/01/2019","19/04/2019","20/04/2019","01/05/2019",
                            "21/05/2019","29/06/2019","16/07/2019","15/08/2019",
                            "18/09/2019","19/09/2019","20/09/2019","12/10/2019",
                            "31/10/2019","01/11/2019","08/12/2019","25/12/2019"
                            ] 

        });
}
```

La funcionalidad datesDisabled no me toma las fechas a deshabilitar, según vi en https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#enableddisabled-dates la forma de utilizar ésta funcionalidad es:

```
  disabledDates: [
                        moment("12/25/2013"),
                        new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 21),
                        "11/22/2013 00:53"
                    ]
```

Probé utilizando `new Date`, `moment()` y la fecha entre comillas, pero no logro que me tome la fecha a deshabilitar, alguna idea de que puedo estar haciendo mal o que me falta?

De antemano, gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que tienes una confusión con la librería que estas usando. Por tu código asumo que estas usando [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) para tener un `datepicker`, pero la documentación que estas viendo es de una librería distinta para tener un `datetimepicker`.

Otro problema es que el formato de fecha se define con la propiedad “format”, no con “dateFormat”, por lo que las fechas que quieres deshabilitar no coinciden en formato.

A continuación, te dejo un ejemplo que utiliza `bootstrap-datepicker` donde se están deshabilitando 2 fechas:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#fecha").datepicker({
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        autoclose: true,
        firstDay : 1,
        minDate : new Date(2005, 0, 1),
        yearRange : '2005:' + String((new Date()).getFullYear() + 1),
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        language: "es",
        datesDisabled: [
            "20/01/2019", // 20 de enero de 2019
            "20/02/2019", // 20 de febrero de 2019
        ],
    });
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>


<div class="d-flex align-items-center h-100">
  <div class="card col-6 offset-3">
    <div class="card-body">
      <label for="fecha">Fecha</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="fecha" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```