# ¿Como hacer para desactivar las fechas de calendario segun una base de datos?

Tags: php, html, jquery, base-de-datos, bootstrap

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de citas medicas para el cual se requiere fechas la cual se almacena en la siguiente base de datos:

```
CREATE TABLE cita(
idcita int auto_increment,
fechacita date not null,
horacita time not null,
descrip text not null,
especialidad varchar(50) not null,
dniusu char(8) not null,
dnidoc char(8),
);
```

Lo que yo quiero estoy queriendo implementar es que las fechas ya ocupadas se desabiliten del calendario para lo cual encontré el siguiente código

```js
$(function () {
    $("#fecha").datepicker({
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        autoclose: true,
        firstDay : 1,
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        language: "es",
        datesDisabled: [
            "20/08/2020", // 20 de enero de 2019
            "21/08/2020", // 20 de febrero de 2019
        ],
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex align-items-center h-100">
  <div class="card col-6 offset-3">
    <div class="card-body">
      <label for="fecha">Fecha</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="fecha" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo encontre en [Propiedad datesDisabled no bloquea fechas de Datepicker](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/241604/propiedad-datesdisabled-no-bloquea-fechas-de-datepicker) pero ahora nose como poner la base de datos el ahi ya que el datesDisabled:' tiene un formato de comas y como puedo hacer para que las fechas guardas en la base de datos en fechacita lo puedo poner en las fechas no disponibles para que se bloqueen.

Answer (score 0):

Segun entiendo ya tienes la lista de fechas desde la base de datos. Estas deben estan guardadas en un array simple y en el formato 'dd/mm/yyyy':

```
<?php
   $rows=query_result("SELECT 
      distinct date_format(fecha_cita,'%d/%m/%Y') as fecha 
      from cita"); // array de registros, formateando la fecha dd/mm/yyyy
   function rowmap($row){
      return $row['fecha'];
   }
   $fechas=array_map("rowmap",$rows); // array de fechas ['dd/mm/yyyy', ...]
?>
```

Y luego puedes incrustar estas fechas en javascript usando `json_encode()`

```
<script>
  fechas_js = <?php echo json_encode($fechas_js) ?>; // fechas_js = [ ... ];
</script>
```

Luego puedes usar esta variable

```
$(function () {
    $("#fecha").datepicker({
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        autoclose: true,
        firstDay : 1,
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        language: "es",
        datesDisabled: fechas_js,
    });
});
```